# How to show $f(x,y,z)=(xy, yz,xz,x^2-y^2)$ is injective?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

I hope this is the function for [Cross-cap](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cross-Cap.html):
$$f: \mathbb{RP}^2 \to \mathbb{RP}^3, (x,y,z) \mapsto (xy, yz,xz,x^2-y^2),$$

Is there a way to show this is injective?

I tried to show $f(x_1,y_1,z_1) = f(x_2,y_2,z_2) \Rightarrow (x_1,y_1,z_1) = (x_2,y_2,z_2)$ but made no progress.

I tried to solve $f(x,y,z) = (a,b,c,d)$ for $x,y,z$ on mathematica, and the [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7Bx%20y,%20y%20z,%20x%20z,%20x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2%7D%20==%20%7Ba,%20b,%20c,%20d%7D,%20%7Bx,%20y,%20z%7D%5D) is scary.

Comment: It is not injective: $f(-x,-y,-z)=f(x,y,z)$. Do you have any restrictions on the domain?

Comment: It is not a one-to-one function, for example check that $f(0,-1,-1)=f(0,1,1)$.

Comment: Oh, then I believe my function for cross-cap is wrong....

Comment: Oh great question!!! The function is defined on $\mathbb{RP}^2$!! I've been wondering what the condition is for....Thank you so much @AndresCaicedo

Comment: With homogeneous coordinates on $\Bbb{RP}^2$, $(\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z) = (x, y, z)$ for any $\lambda \ne 0$, so for any function $f: \Bbb{RP}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^4$ to be *well-defined* (let alone injective), you must have $f(\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z) = f(x, y, z)$ for any $\lambda \ne 0$.

Comment: Or is $f:\mathbb R\mathbb P^2\to\mathbb R\mathbb P^3$?

Comment: Oh, right, thanks @Did

Answer (score 3):

Not injective: $$f(0,0,z)=(0,0,0,0)$$

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, thanks Did. However, I was under the impression that is the conclusion for linear functions?